# ASP.NET MVC 3 use DB other than aspnetdb.mdf to contain membership data, etc

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm creating a web app in ASP.NET MVC 3. I want to use a SQL Server DB (SQL Server Express in development) to house the membership, role, and other related info. So far, I've just been relying on the automatically generated `aspnetdb.mdf` DB, and I've been able to create new users, log in, and log off with no issues. However, I have another DB that contains the tables representing the classes used by the application (using Entity Framework 4, the classes were auto-created based on the DB).

So, I have two DBs, but would like to have just one, because I don't envision my site having a huge number of users, and really I don't see a need for two DBs. In my case, the `aspnetdb.mdf` DB does not have real data yet, so I don't need to worry about preserving that data. So the solution could be combining the two DBs or just not having the `aspnetdb.mdf` DB created in the first place, but rather using the other DB to house user and membership tables, etc. from the start.

My question is multi-part:

1) If I kept both DBs, is there a way to reference the `aspnet_Users` table in the `aspnetdb.mdf` DB from my other DB as a foreign key? I did some searching, and it seems like this is either not possible or quite inconvenient. If this were possible, is it a bad idea?

2) I've done extensive reading on how to combine these into one DB, and I've seen a lot written on it (including here on SO). It looks like the best (or at least a good) way to accomplish this is to use the aspnet_regsql.exe tool to configure my "other DB", then just get rid of the `aspnetdb.mdf` DB and change the connection string in my Web.config file to reference the other DB that I will keep.

I was just about to start making changes, when I came across this statement:

> The Aspnet_regsql tool should not be used with a local installation of SQL Server Express running in user instance mode (that is, the connection string contains User Instance=true).

found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx). My Web.config file has `user instance=true` all over the place. Does this mean I don't need to run the aspnet_reqsql tool? Can I just make the change in the Web.config connection string and delete the `aspnetdb.mdf` DB? Will I need to change the `user instance=true` to something else when I go live?

3) I've gotten to the point where I was assuming the solution to my problem involved the aspnet_regsql tool plus some changes to the Web.config file. If there is an easier/better solution, please let me know.

Just to clarify, I'm in development now using SQL Express, VS Express 2010, and ASP.NET MVC 3. Eventually I will move the site to a hosted production environment. Therefore, any solution I implement will need to carry over to when I go live.

Like I said, I've done quite a bit of reading all over the internet. I've started to form some ideas about how all this stuff works together, but I'm getting to the point where the more I read the more questions I have, and a clear direction eludes me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use one db. If you're using Entity Framework db-first you can create the tables you want in SSMS, run the aspnet_regsql tool against this db and then in Visual Studio generate an .edmx file from these tables. Once that is done, you can use the AspNetMembershipProvider as an API to interact with your users from code, or you can get the users directly from your dbcontext class. I'd recommend using the AspNetMembership provider for creating users. (There is a lot of boilerplate code for this anyways in a new MVC 3 project), but in special cases you might need to interact with the users table directly from your context. Its nice to have options, but try to stay consistent.

In SSMS I would script out your db schema and then run it against a production system when you're ready to go live. Also have a script for data changes too. Keep these under source control.

If you're using Code-First there are a lot of handy nuget packages that have predefined code for your membership class dto's and then you can add your own dto classes right along side of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So does the `user instance=true` have anything to do with it? Also, could you elaborate (or point me to a good source of info) on what you mention as "script out your db schema"? I'm sort of green on some of this stuff, so I'm not exactly sure what that means or how to go about it. I'd assume it means to have a script that automatically recreates all the database tables, constraints, etc. (I guess empty tables?).

Comment: I recommend this training. http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents/web-development. Script out dbschema is right clicking on a table and hitting "Script as" .. to a new query window.